# read numbers from textfile, and check if they are in range

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to load a text file with 1000 numbers or something like that, and i want to check every number if they in range. i try to use vector but cant get i straight.

so basicly i want to check if the first number are bigger or = to the next, and do this many times.

ps: i am extremly new to any type of programming, so plz dont be mean :)

here is my code:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("A1.txt");

    vector<int>array;
    int count;
    double tmp;
    int i;

    myfile >> tmp;
    while (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        myfile >> tmp;
        array.push_back(tmp);
        cout << count;
    }

    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You dont initialize `count`.

Comment: trying not to be mean, but: you need to tell us what is wrong with that code. Does it compile? Does it crash? Does it produce some output? If yes, in what way does that output differ from what you expect? Last but not least, it is always good to ask a question.

Comment: Instead of looping until `count` which you don't know, loop until you reach the end of the file.

Comment: A vital trick which they never seem to teach in programming courses: break a problem into smaller ones and tackle them separately. You want to 1) read many numbers from a file, and 2) compare many numbers, each to the next. Develop these two functionalities in isolation, and get them working perfectly before you splice them together.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a loop until you have read every number:

```
...
double previous, tmp;
myfile >> previous;
array.push_back(previous);//this inserts the first element
//but you have to decide if you need it or not, because it is not compared with any value
while (myfile >> tmp){
    array.push_back(tmp);
    if(previous >= tmp){
        //Do something;
    }
    previous = tmp;//the next previous is the current tmp
}
...
```

Comment: Does `previous` never end up in the vector? And should we make sure the stream is still good after reading `previous`? Otherwise this is a pretty good solution. It appears OP has a slightly different input format (first line is size of array that follows), but the code can be adjusted.

Comment: @AndyG `previous` is just used to compare the previous value with the current one, depending on what the author wants to do inside the  `push_back` can happen inside the `if`. As for verifying if the stream is still good, that is the easy part and the author should be able to do it.

Comment: @M.M you need to do this:   array.push_back(previous);   before entering the while loop